# DevExpress wpf grid scroll using touch screen

Tags: wpf, devexpress, wpfdatagrid, dxperience

I need an grid control for wpf, and very important feature is scrolling grid content using fingers (not using scrollbar, I want to scroll like you scroll content on iPhone).

I downloaded DXperience trial, and run a Demo Center to test DXGrid. But, I can't find any example where I can scroll grid content using my touchscreen without touching scrollbar.

So, is it possible, is there any workaround or have you any suggestion?

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know the DXGrid supports touch scrollig both for WPF and Silverlight since [v2011 vol 2](http://www.devexpress.com/Support/Center/Issues/ViewIssue.aspx?issueid=S36352). There is no special options for WPF needed - it works out-of-the-box (for Silverlight set the AllowTouchScroll property to True to enable touch scrolling).